# How to get the difference in seconds between two datetime fields in Django template?

Tags: django, datetime, django-templates

Minutes is the smallest unit used in Django tags *timesince* and *timeuntil*, not sure how to get the difference in seconds between two datetime fields.

For example, it is 11 seconds between *2021-10-24 15:11:22* and *2021-10-24 15:11:33*.

Comment: Try this: `(date1-date2).seconds`

Comment: @AjayLingayat it doesn't work in Django template

Comment: Then you can create a templatetag for that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, a custom tag should work